# nunit 3 tests on command line as nunit 2.6.4

Tags: nunit, nunit-3.0, nunit-2.6

I have the following Nunit 3 command running in a console window.

```
sh "#{NUNIT}" \
            ' Build\bin\Testing\Functional\Functional.dll 
--test=Functional.Features.Customer.Account.NotificationDetailsFeature.Register'
```

I need to be able to do this with Nunit 2.6.4.
NUnit 2.6.4 doesn't have the `test` flag available. How can I specify a given test in NUnit 2.6.4?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution:
Specify the test, followed by a space, followed by the containing dll.

```
sh "#{NUNIT}" \
            ' /run:Functional.Features.Customer.Account.NotificationDetailsFeature.Register Build\bin\Testing\Functional\Functional.dll'
```